# MathJaX rendering is incorrect on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion default configuration

Tags: support, latex, mathjax, math-se, mac

When viewing a Stack Exchange site such as [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) which uses MathJax for LaTeX rendering, using Safari on Mac OS X 10.7, it produces an incorrect rendering which appears to make everything which should be upright italic and everything which should be italic “double italic”.

[image: (Example rendering error)]

In this example, everything except the second and third `foo` should be upright.

According to [Strange LaTeX fonts in OS/X Lion?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667/strange-latex-fonts-in-os-x-lion) at Meta.Math.SE, a workaround is to disable the new STIX fonts in Mac OS X. However, this is not something Stack Exchange should require of users, so I request that a fix (if it’s MathJax’s problem) or workaround (if it’s Mac OS X’s problem) be implemented in the Stack Exchange MathJax.

Comment: foo foo foo, what is that from? Isn't it supposed to be fufufu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem appears to be gone, and [has been fixed in MathJax upstream](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/152#commits-ref-1955ebb).